# Select different columns from each feature layer to be count values

Tags: arcpy, pandas

How to count values (occurences of values) in each feature layer using a loop?

The problem is that the column names are not the same for all layers.

I have a table that has columns:

```
TheTmpQueryName tablename  query    duplicated
q1                 NTA      query1     0
q2                 IT       query2     1
q3                 INTS     query3     1
```

I want for each row that has in `duplicated = 1` to count values for a specific column.

#### First do filtering of the rows that the count values will be applied

```
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\tableingdb'
field = 'duplicated'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,field) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         if row[0]==1:
          #here how to make a new column that will count how many times occurs?
```

based on this?

```
dict1 = ({'NTA' :  ['AIN'] ,
'IT' : ['CIN'], 
'INTS' : ['KAD'], 'IOT' : ['EK']
```

Where `NTA, IT, INTS` are the layers and `AIN,CIN, EK` the columns on which the count should be based?

Example:

```
NTA(layer)
AIN   COUNT
SSA   21
SSC   1
SDD   98
```

---

```
IT(layer)
CIN COUNT
SRS   23
SCV   14
SDE   12
```

and so on.